# what event i can use on listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Image

https://prnt.sc/10wzspw

now when i click the button at the top and it moves to the next select, which event i can use use that when item is placed on the listox from left to right, i want to trigger the jquery event so it can sow a count behind,

now in the case where i had pushed 3 or 4 items to right, it should combine the values and keep on the adding to the count because as of now i have the following jquery code

```
$(document).on('change',"#_dualselect_sel_groupName",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var array = $(this).map(function() {
        return $(this).find(':selected').data('id');
     }).get();
     alert(array);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'details.cfm?id='+array,
        data : {},
      
        success : function(data) {             
            $('#countusers').html(data).addClass('red');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you make this runnable ?

Comment: runnable means?

Comment: with html as well so that we can test  that on our end .